# How does the explorer/windows taskbar work internally?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to write a very limited taskbar replacement without the start menu and the standard desktop.
But now i wonder how explorer.exe works internally.

1.) How does the taskbar catch minimizing windows?
2.) How do the taskbar get to know when a window opens or closes or somthing? (Is there an api?)

3.) How does explorer.exe enable visual styles? (If it doesn't run all styles are disabled and it looks like win9x)

Answer (score 3):

Review the SetWindowsHookEx() documentation in the MSDN Library.  The important hook type here is WH_SHELL.

Comment: cool: didn't know there was such a hook type, but is says you must register the app as default shell somehow

Comment: I wanted to write it: the documentation

Answer (score 2):

[SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a WH_CBT or WH_SHELL hook (I'm not sure if WH_SHELL works 100% on all systems when explorer is not running)

As far as #3 goes, I don't think I have seen that problem.

Explorer uses a lot of undocumented functions, you should take a look at some of the open source replacement shells or google RegisterShellHook, ShellDDEInit and ARW_HIDE

Answer (score 0):

Check RegisterShellHookWindow, I believe Microsoft added it to avoid having to maitain a 32-bit and a 64-bit hook on newer x64 OS versions.